# Angular custom directive to use an if condition in ng-repeat

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using panels to display the response which is dynamic in nature. I want to differentiate the panels using 2 different colors i.e., if the response has a status of positive, the panel or panel's header must be green. If the status is negative, it must be red. since i'm using a custom directive, I'm not able to use ng-if.

There may be sub arrays present in my response. How do i access and display them in my directive ?

How do i do this ?

I expect the output panel to be in green if the status is positive or red if the status is negative

Answer (score 2):

You can apply conditional classes using [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) angular directive.

Remove the all classes that should be applied on condition. Add those classes as `ng-class`.

But in your case, you need to apply the class before the repeat statement. In that case, since its an array that can contain different status, panel div can only show one status. That you can take with either 0th element of the array or anything else. I have considered 0th.

```
app.directive('showHide', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
        items : '=',

        },
        template:
        `<div class="panel"
            ng-class="{'panel-danger': items[0].Status === 'Negative', 
                       'panel-default': items[0].Status === 'Positive'}">
            <div class="panel-heading panel-height" ng-repeat="item in items">
            <h3 class = "panel-title">
                <p class="font">ID: {{item.Id}}</p></h3><br>
            <p class="font">DESCRIPTION: {{item.Desc}}</p><br>
            <p class="font">STATUS: {{item.Status}}</p><br>
            </div></div></div>`,
    };
});
```

**UPDATE**

Create a new template file for the directive. Instead of having the template in the directive.

**show-hide-directive.js**

```
app.directive('showHide', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            items : '=',
        },
        templateUrl: 'show-hide-directive.html' // <-- Path to the template html file
    };
});
```

**show-hide-directive.html**

```
<div class="panel" ng-class="{'panel-danger': items[0].Status === 'Negative', 'panel-default': items[0].Status === 'Positive'}">
    <div class="panel-heading panel-height" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <h3 class = "panel-title">
            <p class="font">ID: {{item.Id}}</p>
        </h3>
        <br>
        <p class="font">DESCRIPTION: {{item.Desc}}</p><br>
        <p class="font">STATUS: {{item.Status}}</p><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error "unexpected identifier" while using the single quote i.e., 'panel-danger' or 'Negative'. I guess this is because I'm using custom directive. What should be done to resolve this ? or is there a different syntax to be used in custom directives?

Comment: Instead of wrapping the template in the directive, create a new template html file. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks this works fine but the color differentiation is not happening. 'panel-default' is only getting shown. panel-danger is not getting applied

Comment: It will take the `Status` of first `item` in `items`. And I guess the first item i.e. `items[0]` is having `Status = 'Positive'`. If you want different color for all items then you need to make changes in the html.

Comment: I also want to know how to display the sub array from the response

Comment: can u help me with accessing the sub arrays